# unable to start embedded Tomcat when running Eureka Server

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, netflix-eureka

I am just starting with microservices and I want to creat a simple Eureka Server to do my Serviceregistry. For now I just want to run the server on localhost and later I want to add a sample Microservice that registers to it.
The Problem is that I get an error when trying to start Eureka Server.
I develop in Eclipse with Spring and Maven in an ubuntu vm.

> My POM.xml looks like follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>eureka-service-new</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>eureka-service-new</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency> 
             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> 
             <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId> 
             <version>1.19.4</version> 
         </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> and my ErurekaServiceApplication looks like:

```
package com.example.cloud.eurekaservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;


    @EnableEurekaServer
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class EurekaServiceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

> application properties:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
server.port=8080
```

> The error I get is:
>
> 2018-08-01 10:06:03.121 ERROR 14586 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat
>   context. Exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
>   Message: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyFilterRegistration'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'jerseyFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jerseyApplication' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method
>   'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig

The Whole Stacktrace looks like:

```
2018-08-01 10:23:59.117  INFO 14814 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3590fc5b: startup date [Wed Aug 01 10:23:59 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-01 10:23:59.520  INFO 14814 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-01 10:23:59.559  INFO 14814 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbce2302] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-08-01 10:23:59.773  INFO 14814 --- [           main] c.e.c.e.EurekaServiceApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-01 10:23:59.794  INFO 14814 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7cb502c: startup date [Wed Aug 01 10:23:59 CEST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3590fc5b
2018-08-01 10:24:00.714  INFO 14814 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=750f05a0-560d-355e-be40-c524568f20cf
2018-08-01 10:24:00.739  INFO 14814 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-01 10:24:00.870  INFO 14814 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbce2302] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-01 10:24:01.193  INFO 14814 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-01 10:24:01.217  INFO 14814 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-01 10:24:01.217  INFO 14814 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-08-01 10:24:01.221  INFO 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-08-01 10:24:01.328  INFO 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-01 10:24:01.332  INFO 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1538 ms
2018-08-01 10:24:01.523  WARN 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-08-01 10:24:01.525  INFO 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-08-01 10:24:01.535  INFO 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@74c898
2018-08-01 10:24:01.789 ERROR 14814 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jerseyFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyApplication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method 'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig
2018-08-01 10:24:01.827  INFO 14814 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-01 10:24:01.834  WARN 14814 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-08-01 10:24:01.867  INFO 14814 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-01 10:24:01.894 ERROR 14814 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.cloud.eurekaservice.EurekaServiceApplication.main(EurekaServiceApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jerseyFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyApplication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method 'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyApplication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method 'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method 'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.jerseyApplication(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:304) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$654726e3.CGLIB$jerseyApplication$7(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$654726e3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$19e31834.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$654726e3.jerseyApplication(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

When I remove the EnableEurekaServer Annotation, the Tomcat Container runs. 
Is there anything else I have to configure?
The core of my project was made in springio with a EurekaServer dependency.
Thanks

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED**
It turned out that the Problem was a maven dependency. There was an Maven error where `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9` is missing. To solve it I deleted `~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/`

Comment: try adding this dependency in your pom `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: still doesn't work and the error message is the same.

Comment: sorry i gave wrong dependency. try this `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: still not work. Is it possible that I have to change somethong in the EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class. Because the error says that it's not possible to create a jerseyFilterRegistration

Comment: check this https://github.com/pvpkiran/eureka/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Now there is no more Spring output in my console.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Comment: do you have logback settings? if so change log level

Comment: No I haven't setup anything yet. Just installed sts in eclipse and opened a startup project from spring io. Just added this enable Eureka Annotation and that's it. No more properties, .yaml or else

Comment: I also haven't setup a Tomcat in eclipse because I thought the embedded one is automatically used

Comment: I just downloaded the spring sample code from here https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/#initial with the same result. Is there anything to manage with the embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this article talking about Tomcat failure with JDK 9 and higher.
Results in missing JAXB dependencies that were removed from those JDK for EE versions and only present in JDK 8 and lower. Happens with ***Jersey***  (*servlet containers*).

This fix should be applicable to other SpringBoot components: *Zuul, Hystrix* and *Config Server*.

Full Guide: [Spring Cloud Eureka Server / Client](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka)

**Environment:**

- SpringBoot ***2.1.8.RELEASE***
- Spring Cloud: ***Greenwich.SR2***
- JDK: ***11***

Please [read article](https://crunchify.com/java-11-and-javax-xml-bind-jaxbcontext/) and add these:

> And that’s the reason I started getting above exception. Java 11
>   package for ***javax.xml.bind*** does not exist any more.
>
> ```
> Java 7 version: Included and Working
> Java 8 version: Included and Working
> Java 9 version: Deprecated
> Java 10 version: Deprecated
> Java 11 version: Removed
> ```

```
<!--Fix missing dependencies in JDK 9 and higher -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use JDK 8 instead of 10.

Comment: It turns out, that the Problem was the         
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency> I haven't tried to change the java version yet. But thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the application is running on the JRE with the version 9 or obove.
The JAXB APIs are considered to be Java EE APIs and therefore are no longer contained on the default classpath in Java SE 9. In Java 11, they are completely removed from the JDK.

One of the good solution for solving this issue is adding required dependencies, and it is better to use maven profile, you will find the code here:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk11</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>11</jdk>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.7.RELEASE</version>  -->
        2.1.3.RELEASE

```
<groupId>com.pawan.microservice</groupId>
<artifactId>Netflix-Zuul-Api-Gateway-Server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Netflix-Zuul-Api-Gateway-Server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot Netflix-Zuul-Api-Gateway-Server</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <!-- <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2 </spring-cloud.version>   -->
  <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>   
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

use this POM.xml..
In spring boot 2.1.7.Release Zuul api gateway is not support ..so remove the 2.1.7.Release version and use 2.1.3.Release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting BeanException error or Exception initization error it is still not resolved then change your JDK install JDK 1.8 or 9 Exception How to set Eclipse/STS -> Windows ->Preferences ->Java -> Installed JRE-> Add-> Select the directory where you download the JDK (default c:/programFiles/Java/jre1.8) . click next -> select jre1.8->Apply

It resolved for me